# Batch analysis on ImageJ (Fiji)

Tags: imagej

Hi I have 430 files i need to analyse which are in a folder tree

The plugin i am using is this one: http://dev.mri.cnrs.fr/projects/imagej-macros/wiki/Intensity_Ratio_Nuclei_Cytoplasm_Tool

the files before being analysed need to be converted to 16 bit greyscale image, then a specific threshold applied on some of them (all have the same file start name eg, DAPI.tif, DAPI 2.tif) 
Then each DAPI X.tif turned into a mask and analysed using the plugin is analysed with two other files (TRITC X.tif and FITC X.tif) then the results saved.

What is the best way to do this, as it would take me several hours to do this manually? 
Btw I am a beginner when it comes to imageJ so detailed instructions would be useful.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this page of the ImageJ wiki:

https://imagej.net/Batch